Supermicro IPMI Virtual Media
I am trying to link an ISO as virtual media however I am unable to do so.
In my file browser the path works. What am I missing?


The SuperMicro "IPMI" management controller does not support accessing disk images over HTTP. These fields are for specifying a SMB file server (probably SMBv1-only).
